# How to get data upto specific character in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

this is my string

```
   1001|L0|Current|USSD0786|03/06/2015|03339665535|||N|Muhammad Akbar|14301-9830008-9|City Bowra Garhi Tehsil/District Kohat|01/01/1980|Pakistan|01/01/2020||ABC@ABC.COM|Muhammad Zaman|Nadra|1234567890123456789|03/06/2015|41901|529268700|||
```

Now I want to get the name of person muhammad akbar. I am using this but its not giving me the whole name

```
substr(request,53,INSTR(request, '|')-1)
```

can you please solve this problem?

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: @QadeerHussain What is the rule to extract the string? What information is available to extract it? Do you know the position, or the characters between you want to extract?

Comment: yes starting position is 53 up to pipe '|'

Comment: I'm confused.  If you want to get the name, and you are getting the name then what's the problem?

Comment: i am not getting the full name can u please suggest me how can i solve the problem?

Comment: @QadeerHussain Ok, if you need to start from position 53 and then till first occurrence of `|`, then you need nested substr and instr. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to start always at position 53?

In this case you can use this one:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(request, '.+?\|', 53), '|')
FROM ...
```

Or is it more **after 9th pipe '|'**?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea267/12)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test( request ) AS
SELECT '1001|L0|Current|USSD0786|03/06/2015|03339665535|||N|Muhammad Akbar|14301-9830008-9|City Bowra Garhi Tehsil/District Kohat|01/01/1980|Pakistan|01/01/2020||ABC@ABC.COM|Muhammad Zaman|Nadra|1234567890123456789|03/06/2015|41901|529268700|||' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

You can use the regular expression `(^|\|)[^|]*` to match the start of the string or a pipe `(^|\|)` followed by zero-or-more non-pipe characters `[^|]*`. If you combine this with [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_functions_2069.htm) which has a 4th parameter of the occurrence of the expression:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           request,
           '(^|\|)[^|]*',
           1,
           10 -- Change this to get different values
         ),
         '|'
       ) AS value
FROM   Test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea267/12/0)**:

```
|          VALUE |
|----------------|
| Muhammad Akbar |
```

**Query 2**:

If you want all the different values then you can do:

```
SELECT LEVEL,
       REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           request,
           '(^|\|)[^|]*',
           1,
           LEVEL -- Change this to get different values
         ),
         '|'
       ) AS value
FROM   Test
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( request, '\|' ) + 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea267/12/1)**:

```
| LEVEL |                                  VALUE |
|-------|----------------------------------------|
|     1 |                                   1001 |
|     2 |                                     L0 |
|     3 |                                Current |
|     4 |                               USSD0786 |
|     5 |                             03/06/2015 |
|     6 |                            03339665535 |
|     7 |                                 (null) |
|     8 |                                 (null) |
|     9 |                                      N |
|    10 |                         Muhammad Akbar |
|    11 |                        14301-9830008-9 |
|    12 | City Bowra Garhi Tehsil/District Kohat |
|    13 |                             01/01/1980 |
|    14 |                               Pakistan |
|    15 |                             01/01/2020 |
|    16 |                                 (null) |
|    17 |                            ABC@ABC.COM |
|    18 |                         Muhammad Zaman |
|    19 |                                  Nadra |
|    20 |                    1234567890123456789 |
|    21 |                             03/06/2015 |
|    22 |                                  41901 |
|    23 |                              529268700 |
|    24 |                                 (null) |
|    25 |                                 (null) |
|    26 |                                 (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter for `substr` is incorrect, currently your statement looks like `substr(request, 53, 4)`. You need to slightly modify `instr`, start looking from position 53:

```
substr(request, 53, instr(substr(request, 53), '|')-1)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/2162)</sup>

But better is to start from 9th appearance of `'|'` in string and 10th appearance, to make statement independent from that hardcoded value `53`:

```
substr(request, 
       instr(request, '|', 1, 9) + 1, 
       instr(request, '|', 1, 10)-instr(request, '|', 1, 9) - 1)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/2163)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Per your reply to my comments,

> yes starting position is 53 up to pipe '|'

You need a nested **SUBSTR** & **INSTR** query.

```
substr(request,53, instr(substr(request,53), '|', 1, 1)-1)
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  select '1001|L0|Current|USSD0786|03/06/2015|03339665535|||N|Muhammad Akbar|14301-9830008-9|City Bowra Garhi Tehsil/District Kohat|01/01/1980|Pakistan|01/01/2020||ABC@ABC.COM|Muhammad Zaman|Nadra|1234567890123456789|
03/06/2015|41901|529268700|||' request
  3  FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT substr(request,53, instr(substr(request,53), '|', 1, 1)-1) NAME FROM DATA;

NAME
--------------
Muhammad Akbar
```